# Replace in a file with SED a pattern by a SMTP variable

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to replace a string by a environment variable containing a SMTP url (so with @,: and /) in a file. How can I achieve that in a bash command?

I tried with sed but I think the @ is broking my command.

`sed -i -- s/{{MAIL_URL}}/"$MAIL_URL"/g *`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SMTP url may contain `/` characters which coincide/break `sed` expression delimiter `/`.
Change `sed` expresssion delimiter to another character:

```
sed -i "s~{{MAIL_URL}}~$MAIL_URL~g" *
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!